# Running `defun` in graph-mode

Tags: tensorflow

I see code like this in TF:

```
from tensorflow.python.eager import function

...

class _PerDeviceGenerator(dataset_ops.DatasetV2):
  """A `dummy` generator dataset."""

  def __init__(self, shard_num, multi_device_iterator_resource, incarnation_id,
               source_device, element_spec):

    ...

    # TODO(b/124254153): Enable autograph once the overhead is low enough.
    @function.defun(autograph=False)  # Pure graph code.
    def _remote_init_func():
      return functional_ops.remote_call(
          target=source_device,
          args=init_func_concrete.captured_inputs,
          Tout=[dtypes.string],
          f=init_func_concrete)

    self._init_func = _remote_init_func._get_concrete_function_internal()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

    ...

    variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.generator_dataset(
        self._init_captured_args,
        self._next_captured_args,
        self._finalize_captured_args,
        init_func=self._init_func,
        next_func=self._next_func,
        finalize_func=self._finalize_func,
        **self._flat_structure)
    super(_PerDeviceGenerator, self).__init__(variant_tensor)
```

(This code snippet is from TF 1.15.0.)

I'm trying to understand the code.

More specifically, I wonder about `defun` here. I thought `defun` is for eager mode.

But here, this code seems to be used for both eager mode and graph mode. Or is that wrong, and this works only on eager mode? (But below, there is `MultiDeviceIterator`, which has checks like `if context.executing_eagerly()` and later uses `_PerDeviceGenerator` for both eager and graph mode. Or is that broken as well for graph mode? Why the check `executing_eagerly` then?)

What does `defun` do in graph mode?

That `_get_concrete_function_internal` is some internal API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `defun` and `_get_concrete_function_internal` are internal APIs. You should prefer using `tf.function` whenever possible (or `def_function.function` when working on internal code). `defun` is an old API that largely duplicates `function`, and will likely be removed in the future.

That said, `defun` is not just for eager mode (neither is `function`). They both create a TF function, and in graph mode there are "function call" ops that let you call these functions. In eager mode, it just lets you call a TF graph. But in graph mode they let you reduce the size of the graph, in the same way you reduce the size of normal code by factoring common code into functions.

Comment: Small follow up questions: Inside the function, I should then also write normal graph-based code, right? (I used `disable_eager_execution`.) What effect does `autograph` have (with disabled eager execution)? And with `autograph=False`, it must be graph-based code, even with enabled eager mode?

Comment: Yes, functions contain graph code. Autograph lets you write the graph code more easily, and to use `if` instead of `tf.cond`, `and` instead of `tf.logical_and`, etc. The code inside tf.function is always graph code, regardless whether eager execution is enabled or not. Same goes for autograph.