# Parallel execution of TF ops in eager code?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Let's say I have this code ([via](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function)):

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

@tf.function
def f(x):
  while tf.reduce_sum(x) > 1:
    tf.print(x)
    tf.print("hello")
    x = tf.tanh(x)
  return x

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
  session.run(f(tf.random.uniform([5])))
```

As I understand ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964090/running-defun-in-graph-mode)), that code works even with `disable_eager_execution`, also the code inside `f` uses eager-mode.

In graph mode, all TF operations run in parallel (when their inputs or control dependencies are available).

Will the TF operations in eager mode always run sequentially? In this code example, the `tf.print("hello")` could potentially be executed independently. Although I don't know if there are any implicit control dependencies (part of the loop; but does it depend on `tf.print(x)`?). Maybe `tf.print` is also an exception here.

Are there ways to run TF operations in parallel in eager mode?